# the input device is not a TTY - when running docker-compose exec command on Jenkins

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
system("docker-compose -p #{ENV['COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME']} exec #{ENV['BROWSER']} chmod 777 /home/seluser/Downloads")
```

Running this command from ruby test on Jenkins slave causes error
`the input device is not a TTY`

Locally (on Catalina OS) there's no error.

Analogical docker command works successfully on Jenkins:

```
system("docker exec \$(docker ps --filter name=#{ENV['BROWSER']}_1 --format {{.ID}}) sudo chmod 777 /home/seluser/Downloads")
```

What's wrong with docker-compose?

Answer (score 2):

Found solution here https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5696
Need to add `-T' option and run`docker-compose exec -T
`-T Disable pseudo-tty allocation. By default`docker-compose exec` allocates a TTY.